# How do i float the right col into the middle of the left col when browser is getting smaller

Tags: html, css

How do I float the right column into the middle of the left column when browser is getting smaller?

I want to float it between the first and second blocks.

CSS:

```
#leftcol{
    float:left;
    background:#039;
    width:300px

}
#rightcol{
    float:left;
    background:#3C0;
    width: 70%
}

#first{
    background:#F00;
    width:100%
}
#second{
    background:#666;
    width:100%
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div id=leftcol>leftcol
    <div id=first>first block</div>
    <div id=second>second block</div>
  </div>
  <div id=rightcol>rightcol</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the HTML:

```
<div id=first>first block</div>
<div id=rightcol>rightcol</div>
<div id=second>second block</div>
```

Use this CSS:

```
#rightcol{
  float:left;
  background:#3C0;
  width: 70%;
}
#first{
  float:left;
  background:#F00;
  width: 300px;
  clear: both;
}
#second{
  float:left;
  background:#666;
  width:300px;
  clear: both;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ypjqM/)